# Delay css fill on SVG with jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have an SVG of a map of the US.  My goal is to fill in some states when a user clicks a button.  I can't think of a way to delay the fill so each state is delayed by .4 seconds after the last state is filled in.  I think it has something to do with setTimeout, but I'm not super comfortable with JS to know for sure.

I was hoping that there would be some way to do it better like set a variable for the delay time and set the div IDs in an array.  Ideally I was hoping to say:

```
$states = array(Oregon, Washington, California);
$delay = .4;

foreach ($states as $state) {
 /*make a fill change*/
 wait for $delay
}
```

Here is what I have so far...i didn't know how to do the delay so I tried band-aiding it for the Oregon div but after research I don't believe that's the right direction.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('#personal-btn').on("click", function() {
    $('#Oregon').css({ fill: "#d3d3d3" }).fadeOut( 0 ).css({ fill: "#68ABDA" }).delay(800).fadeIn( 400 );
    $('#California').css({ fill: "#68ABDA" });
    $('#Washington').css({ fill: "#68ABDA" });
  });
  $('#commercial-btn').on("click", function() {
    $('#Oregon').css({ fill: "#858585" });
    $('#California').delay( 800 ).css({ fill: "#858585" });
    $('#Washington').css({ fill: "#858585" });
  });
  $('#reset').on("click", function() {
    $('#California, #Oregon, #Washington').css({ fill: "#BE1e2d" });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="216px" height="144px" viewBox="0 0 216 144" enable-background="new 0 0 216 144" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="25.47" y="26.819" fill="#f3f3f3" width="165.059" height="90.361"/>
<rect id="Oregon" x="47.482" y="56.036" fill="#BE1E2D" width="33.936" height="31.928"/>
<rect id="Washington" x="91.032" y="56.036" fill="#BE1E2D" width="33.936" height="31.928"/>
<rect id="California" x="134.582" y="56.036" fill="#BE1E2D" width="33.936" height="31.928"/>
</svg>
<button id="personal-btn">Personal</button>
<button id="commercial-btn">commercial</button>
<button id="reset">reset to red</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with ES6 `async` vanilla JS functions. In the following demo, I create a `delay` function which returns a promise which resolves after a specified delay. You can then `await` that promise resolution in your for-loop (as long as your loop is also inside an async function, which is why it's wrapped in an async lambda).

The result you see is 50 `<p>` elements disappearing one at a time, 400ms between each one.

This is of course a demo, and you can swap out the body of the for-loop for whatever you want, such as changing styles of your SVG elements.

```js
//Populate with <p>s for demo
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const pCount = 50;

for(let i = 0; i < pCount; i++)
{
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = i;
  div.appendChild(p);
}

//Delay function
const delay = async(duration) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, duration);
  });
};

//Delay with async function, 400ms
const delayTime = 400;
(async () => {
  const children = Array.from(div.children);
  for(let i = 0; i < pCount; i++)
  {
    const p = children[i];
    p.style.opacity = 0;
    await delay(delayTime);
  }
})();
```

```css
div
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p
{
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't necessarily want the div to disappear, but just to change color.  Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: You can put your `$.css` call in the for loop. Making them disappear was just an example.